# MS Access 2003 how to do a max - min calculation in a form using multiple fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a form with multiple fields. I have a field that I need to find the max and min of the numbers entered and subtract the min from the max.

Basically, the user will input data into the form:

- field1 = 5
- field2 = 4
- field3 = 2
- field4 = 1
- field5 = 3

  fieldcalc = (max(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)) - (min(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5))

should return 4

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this:

```
Public Function ReturnMinOrMax(intMinOrMax As Byte, ParamArray vals()) As Long
'intMinOrMax: 0 for min, non-0 for max

    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Variant

    i = vbNull

    For Each v In vals
        If IsNull(v) = False Then
            If IsNull(i) = True Then i = v

            Select Case intMinOrMax
                Case 0
                    If v < i Then i = v
                Case Else
                    If v > i Then i = v
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    ReturnMinOrMax = CLng(i)

End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
fieldcalc = ReturnMinOrMax(1, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) - ReturnMinOrMax(0, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
```

The function takes a flag to return min or max as well as a ParamArray which you can pass as many fields as you want.  Just pass it all your values and perform the subtraction operation.